# CSS display:none; if content:"}";

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, curly-braces

I have this incredibly irritating curly brace that I can't get rid off.

I have a WordPress website running and installed a plugin.
This plugin adds a right-curly brace `}` at the top of the page.
Directly below the `<body>`

I went through the entire plugin-pages but couldn't find it.
Now I would like to hide it with some CSS, but the curly brace has no class or id or whatever.

I tried the following:

```
body{
  content:"}";
  display:none;
}
```

But obviously that just clears out the entire page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should fix the actual issue instead of monkey patching some bodged code ...

Comment: Instead of fixing the things in the wrong way, search for the issue, 'couldnt find it' is not an excuse

Comment: @Mr.Alien Wordpress plugins are a minefield. Imagine trying to find a single brace in there!

Comment: You are all absolutely right, but after three days and no luck with the owner of the plugin for assistance I'm kinda forced to do this.

Comment: Are you implying he can't use `ctrl + f` and find out if there's an extra bracket or one outside of the php tags? @RGraham. It doesn't sound too hard.

Comment: @RGraham it takes a donkey forever, with proper debugging it won't take much time... use the right tools for right thing

Comment: @Mr.Alien Meh, it's a *plugin*... Sometimes you have to justify how much your time is worth against how easy a patch is. It's not the OP's job to waste time on something somebody else should fix. I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying it's not quite black & white sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain old Javascript solution would be to test for a node of type `TEXT_NODE` at the first index and to make sure its text is exactly `{` - I've trimmed whitespace as an example, but perhaps you don't need to.

```
var firstChild = document.body.childNodes[0];
if(firstChild && firstChild.nodeType === 3 && firstChild.textContent.trim() === "{") {
    document.body.removeChild(firstChild);
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jtroqLnk/)

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do (and the right thing), is to find where that pesky `}` is coming from and remove it there! It is not a good idea to use code to remove it.

It is a **terrible** idea to try and attempt to do this by code. By giving up this easily looking for a `}` in your code is a bad sign.

If you know what plugin is causing this go back and keep checking until you find it. That is not only the best fix, but the proper one.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I'm out of time and patience for this month's update round.

Comment: If it's a plugin, updating it at source (Github?) is even better. Otherwise updating could just re-introduce the bug.